# sending SMS from android & eclipse

Tags: android, sms

I'm trying to send sms from one emulator to another emulator, 
I've 3 string, then I'm adding this 3 string to one string & then trying to send an SMS, but its just sending `null'.

```
private String fm = mSelectedItemExam+" "+mSelectedItemBoard+" "+mSelectedItemYear;

public void Submit(View view) {      
     // sendSMS function
     sendSMS("5556", fm);
}

private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
}
```

Check the [Screenshot](http://prntscr.com/79ltpc) to see what I'm receiving on another emulator

Comment: Where is the value of mSelectedItemExam, mSelectedItemBoard, mSelectedItemYear being initialised?

Comment: those are on top, those are assigned as string, if I send only mSelectedItemExam instead of fm then its send succesfull. I means working fine.
this is working fine
public void Submit(View view) {      
     // sendSMS("5556", location [index]);
            //OR you can also send sms using below code.

      sendSMS("5556", mSelectedItemExam);

}
 private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
    {
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
    }

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "default content"); 
        sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
public void Submit(View view) {

     private String fm = mSelectedItemExam+" "+mSelectedItemBoard+" "+mSelectedItemYear;

     // sendSMS function
     sendSMS("5556", fm);
}

private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help. I've also done an edit to your question. Please accept if its good.

Comment: already accepted, you can also vote up for this problem, so others can get help form it

Answer (score 0):

```
  Log.i("Send SMS", "");



            String phoneNo = "1212";
            String message = "msms";


               SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
               smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
```

Comment: This is working fine, but my problem is here sendSMS("5556", fm);
it can't send perfect sms, http://prntscr.com/79ltpc please check the screenot